Another wooden bottom of bay/oriel window in need of repair!
Would anybody be able to suggest how best repair this? Seems wood (I don't have much idea, as you can imagine).
Thank you so much!
Enrique




find the leak where water is getting in. 2) fix the leak. 3) replace the bottom.


Thank you! Ok, will do 1) and 2). Does 3) mean all the bottom or just the corners? Can anything be used? Would it be big job? handyman or carpenter? Sorry again, clueless here. Thank you as well for help.

The bottom looks like it's just a piece of plywood (which would be expected). It would be far more difficult and time consuming to replace parts of instead of the whole thing. Finding the leak might involve a roofer or carpenter. Who fixes it probably depends on who finds it. You could DIY, or it might be a massive renovation. Can't tell until the problem is identified.
